# ¿Por qué el uso de + en las librerías gradle de Android es una mala práctica?

Tags: android, android-studio, buenas-prácticas

Cuando empecé con Android, en algunos tutoriales usaban el signo de + cuando indicaban ciertas librerías en el `gradle`, por ejemplo:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Yo interpreté que esta era una forma de compilar siempre la última sub-versión (de la versión 26 en este caso). Pero Android Studio me pone una advertencia algo inquietante que parece contradecir lo que yo creía:

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and
>   unrepeatable builds (com.android.support:support-v4:26.+) less...
>
> Using + in dependencies lets you automatically pick up the latest
>   available version rather than a specific, named version. However, this
>   is not recommended; your builds are not repeatable; you may have
>   tested with a slightly different version than what the build server
>   used. (Using a dynamic version as the major version number is more
>   problematic than using it in the minor version position.)

Traducido sería:

> Evite usar + en los números de versión; puede provocar compilaciones
>   impredecibles e irrepetibles (com.android.support:support-v4:26.+) ...
>
> Usar + en dependencias le permite recoger automáticamente la última
>   versión disponible en lugar de una versión específica con nombre. Esto
>   no es recomendable; tus construcciones no son repetibles; Es posible
>   que haya probado con una versión ligeramente diferente de la que
>   utilizó el servidor de compilación. (Usar una versión dinámica como el
>   número de versión principal es más problemático que usarlo en la
>   posición de versión menor).

No termino de entender la advertencia de Android y quisiera saber por qué el uso de +  en las librerías es una mala práctica.

Comment: Yo entiendo que es simplemente una cuestión de que cuando se publica una nueva versión de la librería, deberías testear tu aplicación contra esa versión antes de darla por válida. Si le pones el +, la proxima vez que compiles estarás usando esa nueva versión sin darte cuenta y sin las debidas pruebas de funcionamiento.

Comment: ¿Según tú, @Pikoh, es sólo una cuestión con respecto a probar la App?

Comment: Si, yo creo que es eso nada mas. Si fuera algo mas grave probablemente se suprimiría la opción de +. Sin embargo, aqui lo único que hace es advertirte de que usandolo es posible que tengas problemas cuando se publique una nueva version de la biblioteca.

Comment: Bueno, y a parte del tema de tests, está el tema de que si se publica una nueva versión de una biblioteca, al compilar automáticamente va a ser usada, con lo que el apk generado no será igual que uno compilado anteriormente. En ese caso, podrías encontrarte con dos apk que piensas que son iguales pero en realidad tienen comportamientos diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque solo se indica que el uso de + al definir la dependencia de una library en nuestro proyecto puede

> "conducir a compilaciones impredecibles e irrepetibles"

En realidad son dos detalles por los cuales no es recomendable el uso de +, si realizamos la definición de dependencias con +, por ejemplo:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

esto indicaría el uso de la última versión de las Library, aunque `Android Studio` sugiere, o alenta el uso de las últimas versiones en nuestros proyectos, esto puede provocar algunos problemas.

Los problemas que podemos experimentar son:

> - El primer problema es que podemos encontrar bugs o funcionamientos inadecuados. Por experiencia, en realidad una última versión no puede
>     ser estable y tener algún tipo de bug, por eso regularmente sugiero
>     usar versiones anteriores que fueron previamente probadas por los
>     usuarios.
> - El segundo problema es que al actualizar a la última versión en algún momento podemos encontrar que necesitamos realizar algún cambio
>     en un método o clase, incluso estos podrían no existir o cambiar de
>     nombre.

El segundo problema no me parece tan critico ya que simplemente debemos realizar modificaciones del código, pero en cambio el primero el cual Google no lo menciona con exactitud, si es un gran problema, puesto que en ocasiones podemos no encontrar un problema realizando testing, pero lo encontramos hasta que la aplicación se encuentra en producción.

Answer (score 1):

Es claro que es una mala practica, el problema es que el + indica que va a traer la última versión del repositorio.

Ahora, Cual es el problema con esto? que muchas veces hay cambio de API en las librerías, como en el caso de Glide 3x y 4x, si tienes tu aplicación que incluye la librería "libreriav2" y llama a un método digamos así:

```
libreria.metodoA();
```

De pronto entras al siguiente día y la librería se actualizó , como le habías puesto +, entonces ahora coge la última versión que es "libreríav3", en esa versión el métodoA() ya no existe, ahora se llama de otra forma:

```
libreria.metodoNuevoA();
```

Por lo que tu aplicación no va a poder compilar hasta que corrijas todos los errores dependientes de esa lib (O declares la versión correcta directamente sin +). Se entiende?

Muchas de las librerías tienen su wiki de migración cuando hay cambios severos, por ejemplo en Glide: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html

Comment: ¿Y qué consecuencias podría tener esto en una App que ya está compilada y subida en Play Store?

Comment: si ya está compilada no hay problema, el tema es al compilar mientras desarrollas.